# MySQL - Another way to do this to reduce the amount of Joins? - Or short hand syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I completed a homework assignment (prompt and more details below), and one of my answers looked like this:

```
SELECT Student.SSN, FirstName, LastName, Section.SectionNo, Section.Instructor
FROM  Course Join Enrolls ON Course.CourseNo = Enrolls.CourseNo
JOIN  Student ON Student.SSN = Enrolls.SSN
JOIN  Section ON Section.SectionNo = Enrolls.SectionNo AND Section.CourseNo = Course.CourseNo
WHERE CourseName = 'Data structure and Algorithms'
```

I was wondering, is there another way to accomplish the same thing while not making the code look so cluttered? Is there maybe a more efficient or at least short-hand syntax way to do what I did?

---

**Prompt:** Get the information (SSN, first name and last name) about students who take the course ‘Data structure and Algorithms’. Also get the section number in which they have enrolled in the course, as well as the instructor of the section.

Here are how my tables look like:

**STUDENT**

```
SSN         FirstName    LastName    Street            City         State    Zip
1237456787  Dilly        Dob         1233 Revem Court  Sacramento   CA       56123
1237456788  Filly        Fob         1243 Roasm Road   Sacramento   CA       21234
1237456789  Billy        Bob         1234 Random Lane  Sacramento   CA       12145
```

**SECTION**

```
CourseNo    SectionNo    Instructor
CSC300      1            Prof Cool
CSC300      2            Prof Cool
CSC300      3            Prof Cool
CSC133      2            Prof SuperCool
CSC133      1            Prof SuperCool
CSC133      3            Prof SuperCool
CSC137      2            Prof NotSoCool
```

**ENROLLS**

```
SSN         SectionNo   CourseNo
1237456787  1           CSC300
1237456788  1           CSC300
1237456789  1           CSC300
1237456789  2           CSC133
1237456789  2           CSC137
```

**COURSE**

```
CourseNo   CourseName                                 Department
CSC300     Advanced Database Management Systems       Computer Science
CSC133     Data Structure and Algorithms              Computer Science
CSC137     Computer Organization and Digital Circuits Computer Science
```

---

**RESULT SHOULD BE**

```
SSN        FirstName    LastName    SectionNo    Instructor
123456789  Billy        Bob         2            Prof SuperCool
```

Comment: it's the formatting of your SQL. Still looks cluttered?

Comment: @almasshaikh Well it looks better, but I'm still wondering whether so many JOIN's is the right approach? I'm new to SQL so I don't know if I'm missing some sort of other SQL operator that might make this query simpler if you know what I mean.  If there's not, that's fine, I'm just curious.

Comment: You need them as you have relation between those to fetch the appropriate values. For instance, If you have courseNo handy then you could get rid of join between course and enrolls. Another way would be subquery for remove further join to get just course for data structure and Algorithms.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks for confirming that I need those joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is about as minimal as you can get based on the description and qualifiers.  A few notes, especially for learning and longer term sanity.  whenever dealing with more than one table in a query, get in the habit of always qualifying with table.column (or alias.column) for readability, especially if table names are long, apply a shorter "alias".

Second, and this is more just stylish formatting and comes in nice for joins to know where things are coming from.  INDENT... and also, in the joins, I always try to list my first table as the FIRST-side of the join equality.  Comes in easier when reading and implementing LEFT JOIN criteria later on in your education...

```
SELECT 
      S.SSN, 
      S.FirstName, 
      S.LastName, 
      Section.SectionNo, 
      Section.Instructor
   FROM  
      Course C
         Join Enrolls E
            ON C.CourseNo = E.CourseNo
            JOIN  Student S 
               ON E.SSN = S.SSN
            JOIN  Section 
               ON C.CourseNo = Section.CourseNo
               AND E.SectionNo = Section.SectionNo
   WHERE 
      C.CourseName = 'Data structure and Algorithms'
```

Notice the enrolls table is child relation to course.  Student is child relation to Enrolls, but so too is the Section child to Enrolls.  But the "ON" clause is looking at both the course and enrolls tables.

Again, personal learning preference style on querying.  Also, by having all columns lined up, if you are looking for a specific one, look straight down the list and add/remove as necessary.

Additionally, for tables, I strongly suggest getting auto-increment column for IDs, especially when SSN (private info) could be bad, such as illegal or no such SSN available for students.  You could still look up a person by name and have this internal auto-increment the basis of the enrollment table.  If someone DOES have an SSN (or Green-Card number, student VISA, whatever), the internal ID won't be any conflict.

Comment: We each have our own formatting style - but I completely agree that it's good to have one. Likewise, agree with qualification of columns and order of joins - but also, use table aliases throughout! Anyway, the key rule is consistency.

Comment: @DRapp Nice and clear answer which answered my questions about whether or not I can minimize the query. Thanks!  Normally my I hit the "beautify" button in MySQL Workbench because I like that format, I'm just not very good at formatting in the Stack Overflow editor yet (as you can see if you look at the original edit of the post).  And for the last part, I would definitely use the auto increment column for ID's, but my teacher told us to follow the requirements exactly and she said for the SSN's to be a primary key, so I'm just doing what I'm told haha.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT st.SSN, st.FirstName, st.LastName, se.SectionNo, se.Instructor
FROM STUDENT st
INNER JOIN ENROLLS en ON st.SSN = en.SSN
INNER JOIN SECTION se ON en.SectionNo = se.SectionNo and en.CourseNo = se.CourseNo
INNER JOIN COURSE co ON en.CourseNo = co.CourseNo
WHERE CourseName = 'Data structure and Algorithms'
```

Not unless you change the data source this is the minimum you need to get what is expected.

Unless you could use the CourseNo in the WHERE clause rather than the name?

```
SELECT st.SSN, st.FirstName, st.LastName, se.SectionNo, se.Instructor
FROM STUDENT st
INNER JOIN ENROLLS en ON st.SSN = en.SSN
INNER JOIN SECTION se ON en.SectionNo = se.SectionNo and en.CourseNo = se.CourseNo
WHERE se.CourseNo = 'CSC133'
```

Comment: @almasshaikh not among the requested fields

Comment: Yup, only `SSN, FirstName, LastName, SectionNo, Instructor` was requested

Comment: I just ran the above code and it gave me two extra results:

123456789 Billy Bob 2 Prof Cool
123456789 Billy Bob 2 Prof NotSoCool

I like the shorthand though!

Comment: Try it now, used the section number from section rather than enrolls

Comment: I think it gave the extra 2 results when it joined the SectionNo's so that's why in my original code I put "Section.SectionNo = Enrolls.SectionNo AND Section.CourseNo = Course.CourseNo" to filter out the courses that didn't have the right name.

Comment: @Matt So its edited with where clause.. whihc was missing earlier

Comment: @Matt doesn't even run. "Syntax error: unexpected INNER" at the INNER after the "and"

Comment: removed the stray `and` :)

Comment: Just tried removed it but the query still returns 3 results instead of 1 :\  I'm going to sleep but I'll check again in the morning

Comment: Yup it works now.  It's basically the same as the edited code above  but with added renaming and a few of the joins moved around.  Thanks for showing me how the renaming works though, that'll be useful in the future

Comment: You could possibly save a line by using the second block of code above by searching on courseNo instead of name

Comment: I would use it, but in the prompt the Professor requires that we use that specific Course Name instead.

Comment: Yeh thought as much, maybe give it as an alternative as well as the regular answer

Comment: FWIW, I like to use single letter aliases for source tables and two-letter aliases for linking tables, but maybe that's just me ;-)

Comment: Yeh i like that naming convention also, keep it simple and clean